# What is the most appropriate python data structure to keep the result of pairwise computations over 2 dictionaries?

Tags: python

I have 2 dictionaries with long as the type of the values. I want to apply some computation at every possible combination of 2-values from the 2 dictionaries and maintain a data structure that will keep the result and the input values. i.e: key(a),value(a),key(b),value(b),f(value(a),value(b)) . What sort of data structures would you suggest for this operation
[image]

Comment: I think you meant `key(a),values(a),key(b),values(b),f(value(a),value(b))`   Right ?

Comment: yes you are right, i fixed it in the original post

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your computation only depends on the values of the dictionary, you should reformulate your problem statement to take only an iterable of values, and not dictionaries.

You can use tuples as dictionary keys:

```
import itertools
Adict = {"x": 1, "y": 2, "z":3}
Bdict = {"foo": 4, "bar": 5, "baz":6}
A,B = Adict.values(),Bdict.values()
def comp(a, b):
  return a * b # Insert complicated computation here
res = {(a,b):comp(a,b) for a,b in itertools.product(A, B)}
```

Comment: It seems that is more appropriate to take the cartesian product:

Comment: Also your code is not syntax correct at line 4. The itertools.permutations() return all possible combinations of 1 list http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations

Answer (score 1):

Either a list of dicts or a more complex iterator defining your own custom object to represent the data and ways of iterating over the data by the different keys you have.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest a dictionary with:

- keys being tuples of tuples: `( (key(a), value(a))  ,  (key(b), value(b)) )`
- values being long (if it's the type returned by your function f(a,b))